# Spring Cloud config server client is not detecting the contents from config server

Tags: spring-cloud-config

In my spring config server client, in "bootstrap.properties" i have mentioned the below, but it is not picking up the configurations from spring server:

spring.application.name=RestClientGreeter

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888

---

My config server runs at "http://localhost:8888" and while testing in Rest client it works perfectly fine

Get request in rest testing client: "http://localhost:8888/RestClientGreeter/default"

### Output I get:
{
"name": "RestClientGreeter",
"profiles": [
"default"
],
"label": null,
"version": "fdba8831b3eb54970f7f97eafdf1d606b8857318",
"state": null,
"propertySources": [
{
"name": "file:////Users/partha/localgitrepo/RestClientGreeter.properties",
"source": {
"management.security.enabled": "false",
"server.port": "12341",
"eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone":"http://localhost:9865/eureka/"
}
}
],
}

Logs:

2020-12-08 09:20:46.569  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.demo.SpringRestClientApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-08 09:20:46.669  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-12-08 09:20:46.669  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-12-08 09:20:47.887  WARN 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-12-08 09:20:48.045  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=4c5eeb67-2448-3311-bab7-3a4b24606f79
2020-12-08 09:20:48.080  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.example.demo.GreetCaller' of type [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-08 09:20:48.978  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-08 09:20:48.993  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-08 09:20:48.993  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-12-08 09:20:49.099  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-08 09:20:49.099  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2429 ms
2020-12-08 09:20:49.228  WARN 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-12-08 09:20:49.228  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-12-08 09:20:49.250  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@dc91c88
2020-12-08 09:20:49.558  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/Users/partha/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.1/spring-core-5.3.1.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2020-12-08 09:20:49.840  WARN 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2020-12-08 09:20:49.840  WARN 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2020-12-08 09:20:49.840  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2020-12-08 09:20:50.188  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-08 09:20:50.675  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses RestTemplate.
2020-12-08 09:20:50.770  WARN 89553 --- [  restartedMain] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it to the classpath.
2020-12-08 09:20:50.784  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-12-08 09:20:50.852  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2020-12-08 09:20:50.922  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2020-12-08 09:20:50.930  INFO 89553 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration